# Sidebar width issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, sidebar

I start with showing you my "site".

[image: My Problem] "My problem"

The header will always be centered with a width of 1140px.
The main content will have width of ~70% and a max width of 912px.

My problem is that the sidebar won't keep it's correct width.

If you look at the site in the "design" resolution, it looks right but if you make the window bigger, it doesn't follow. It should always stay so the sidebar content always is "inside" the the left edge of the header.

How would I achive this?
The sidebar have a width of ~23% and it looks right if you keep the window at 1300px wide (that's the width the design came in).

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided your html/css code, preferably in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) format

Comment: It looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gx4jb/20/
Couldn't do it exactly as it is cause the divs disapeared. The sidebar is absolute positioned and the main div has margin-left so it's always in the correct plays (inline with the right edge of the header).

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly I don't think it is possible to create a responsive layout. If the centered header can be smaller than 1140px while the main content and sidebars are set to have percentage widths, then there will always be a chance that the sidebar+main content will be wider than the header, hence the left side of the sidebar will always be "outside" the left margin of the header.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stated requirements, the header will have a min-width of 1140px so my 'solution' is based on that figure. For full responsiveness this should really be a % and media queries used.

By using a couple of extra wrappers I think we can mange what you are after.

** BASIC HTML **

```
<header>
  <div class="inner">
    THIS IS MY HEADER AREA
  </div>
</header>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="inner">
  THIS IS MY NAV BAR
</div>
</div>

  <aside>
    ASIDE
  </aside> 

<div class="inner clearfix">

  <div class="content">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

** CSS ** (including some colors so you can see ahat is happening.

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

html {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header {
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:lightgreen;
}

.inner {
  width:1140px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  }

header .inner {
    background:lightblue;
}

.nav {
  height:50px;
  background:pink;
  line-height:50px;
}

.nav .inner {
  background:NavajoWhite;
}



aside {
  width:20%;
  min-width:218px;
  height:400px;
  background:blue;
  margin-top:10px;
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;

}

.content{
  height:450px;
  background-color: orange;
  width:70%;
  float:right;
  max-width:912px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xswjt)

Comment: The thing is, the site have a MAX-WIDTH of 1140. So the header will never be bigger than 1140, but it can get smaller. The main content can not be bigger than 912px, but can get smaller. So the problem is that the sidebar stays to the left and leaves a big gap between the sidebar and main div.

Comment: Ok, then you are definitely going to need some media queries to change the % width of the `.content` div. At the moment just changing the width of the `.inner` div to a max-width of 1140 makes the page pretty responsive. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Aghba How small do you want this to go?